# SQLite returns single row even though I am not using GROUP BY

Tags: sqlite

I have the following SQLite database

[image]

I expect there will be 3 rows of result being returned, if I make the following query.

```
SELECT name, sum(heart) FROM test_table;
```

However, even though I am **not** using `GROUP BY`, only 1 row is being returned.

```
C:\Users\yan-cheng.cheok\Desktop>sqlite3.exe
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .restore abc
sqlite> SELECT name, sum(heart) FROM test_table;
Record3|102
```

I am expecting result :

```
Record1|102
Record2|102
Record3|102
```

As in convientional SQL, if I do not use `GROUP BY`, every individual rows will be returned.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Is there anything I can make all 3 rows returned?

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as "convientional SQL".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this you can use `cross join`

```
SELECT a.name, b.totalHeart
FROM test_table a,
    (
        SELECT SUM(heart) totalHeart
        FROM test_table
    ) b
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is [documented](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

> If the SELECT statement is an aggregate query without a GROUP BY clause, then each aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated once across the entire dataset. Each non-aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated once for an arbitrarily selected row of the dataset. The same arbitrarily selected row is used for each non-aggregate expression. Or, if the dataset contains zero rows, then each non-aggregate expression is evaluated against a row consisting entirely of NULL values.

You could do this:

```
sqlite> select a.name, b.s from abc as a, (select sum(heart) as s from abc) as b;
Record1|102
Record2|102
Record3|102
```